SPM: Expose transitive dependency types
I'm developing a Swift Package distributed via Swift Package Manager (SPM). I have other dependencies (Swift packages) that my package depends on. Is it possible to expose types (classes, structs, etc.) defined in the dependencies to the client app? So given;
ClientApp -> MyPackage -> DependencyA (contains Person class)
Is there a way to make ClientApp see the Person class without it also importing DependencyA?

SPM = Swift Package Management, right? Sorry for a silly question, but I'm not familiar with Swift.

@GregBurghardt Yes, "Swift Package Manager". And no worries, all questions are allowed.

The question, as it is asked, can be viewed as a question asking for coding help. Questions asking for coding help are off-topic for this community, however if the question were rephrased to focus on the design problem that requires ClientApp to need a reference to a type in DependencyA then I think it would be on-topic.

I've worked with transitive dependencies and they are evil. Do not use them even if your platform allows it.

@Basilevs Thanks for the insight

Ah... Classic of the exceedingly toxic Stack forums. One downvote and no answers even after a bounty. I just got a wonderful answer for free on another forum within minutes of posting. I've seen people here challenge others and downvote even when they have no clue about the subject matter. Fantastic I tell you. Fantastic...

@Fourth people do not want to risk spending effort on off-topic question. Try to fit it better.

@Fourth Have you considered creating wrappers?

I see two viable options:

Define a "Person" interface in MyPackage which is implemented by a type in DependencyA. The ClientApp has a "Person" abstraction, but the chain of dependencies stops at MyPackage. The dependency inversion principle is applicable here. CliantApp should depend on MyPackage. Moving the "Person" abstraction into MyPackage allows for this relationship without requiring ClientApp to know about DependencyA. This assumes you can change DependencyA.

In cases where you cannot change DependencyA, create a type in MyPackage to represent this abstraction to ClientApp. Internally, the "Person" type can use delegation or the proxy pattern to forward calls to the proper type in DependencyA.


The two options above do not require ClientApp to directly reference a type in DependencyA, but ClientApp will still need to pull in that dependency. The jar file will still need to be deployed and loaded into memory. If the intention is to literally not include that jar file, then I can think of a couple other options:

Embed DependencyA in MyPackage. The jar file for MyPackage would also contain DependencyA. I haven't the foggiest clue if this is even possible in Java. Plus, if DependencyA needs to be eliminated due to a security vulnerability, simply embedding the jar file in another jar file won't really solve the problem. It just makes MyPackage vulnerable.

Move MyPackage into a web service. ClientApp calls MyPackage via web API endpoints. It's also not really a "package" anymore. MyPackage becomes a client for this new web API.


